# Mapping a `string.join` with a list of strings returns unxpected list of strings

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.6

I tried following instructions:

```
>>> values ['9', '31', '32']
>>> map('abc'.join, values)
and got:
['9', '3abc1', '3abc2']
```

but i expected:

```
['abc9', 'abc31', 'abc32']
```

why am i mistaken?

Just for the record i circumvented it with:

```
>>> map(lambda x: 'abc%s' % x, values)
```

But i'm still puzzled by the behaviour of the 1st map-construct!

*Thanks for all the insightful answers. They are all correct and helpful, so i had to threw the dice to choose which to accept - i would have accepted any of them ;-)*

Comment: The latter can be also written simpler as `map('abc{0}'.format, values)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will call subsequently

```
'abc'.join('9')
```

which gives `'9'` since there is only one element in the given argument to `join`, then

```
'abc'.join('31')
```

since `'31'` is similar to `['3', '1']` the result is `'3abc1'` and so on.

Answer (score 5):

What you want is

```
["abc" + x for x in values]
```

The method `str.join()` uses the part before the dot as the string by which to join an iterable of other strings.  That's why

```
"abc".join(["12", "34"])
```

results in

```
"12abc34"
```

If you simply pass in a string as iterable, the individual characters are the items of this iterable:

```
"abc".join("1234")
```

results in

```
"1abc2abc3abc4"
```

Answer (score 1):

`'abc'.join(l)` uses `abc` as a delimiter when joining the items in `l`

When mapping it with your `values` list, the method is called once for every item in `values`. As strings are iterable in Python, every char is then used as an item.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you expected that. You're asking to run `'abc'.join(x)` for each of the elements in values. Each of those elements is a string, which is iterable: in effect, it's a list of its characters. So `'abc'.join('31')` is the same as `'abc'.join(['3', '1'])` which gives the result you get.

Answer (score 1):

in the case you just want to  concat string, use `str + str`, or `str.format()` with a correct `{}` inside string

```
values = ['9', '31', '32']
map('abc{}'.format, values)
```

or more simply with list comprehension:

```
values = ['9', '31', '32']
['abc{}'.format(v) for v in values]
```